# How to use Ctrl-Insert to copy from XTerm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

In applications like Firefox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> work like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (modifying the *secondary* clipboard), but in XTerm they do *not* work like [the common <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a5b00babcf62404da6b8a5fc5dd1ab09d996a4ff/.Xresources#L14):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> does not change the clipboards, and instead prints literally `;5~` on the current prompt.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> pastes the *primary* clipboard instead of the secondary.

Can I fix this in [`.inputrc`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a508ac5ef5643a30d9e467603b11d31b807dcbef/.inputrc) or otherwise? It would be nice to have two-stroke [cross-platform cut and paste shortcuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Common_keyboard_shortcuts) everywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

xterm, whose conventions were established many years before Firefox, and even the web, was invented, is controlled by *application resources*. These are merged from several places, including files like `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm`, and also information held by the X11 server seen with `xrdb -q`.  You can override these resources by placing, for example, things like the following in the file `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations:       #override\n\
 Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n\
 Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n
```

This binds <kbd>ctrl-shift-v</kbd> to inserting the clipboard contents.
I'm not clear exactly what you wanted, so check the [man page](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uxterm.htm)
for the functions and the PRIMARY, SECONDARY and CUT_BUFFER0 selections.

---

You can presumably add (don't forget the backslash on preceding lines):

```
Shift <Key>Insert: insert-selection(SECONDARY)\n\
Ctrl  <Key>Insert: copy-selection(SECONDARY)\n
```

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to *[How can I copy text from xterm (Awesome, Debian, VirtualBox)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225062/how-can-i-copy-text-from-xterm-awesome-debian-virtualbox/293856#293856)*, including part of the suggested answer.

However: by way of background, `xterm` receives X events (which you can see using `xev`), and handles those in different ways:

- for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd>, xterm sees the events for the control- and insert-keys, and constructs a sequence of characters to send to your application, e.g., `^[[28;5~`
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd> is handled differently because it is part of the [default **`translations`** resource](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) for xterm.  That is a feature of the X Toolkit library which comes *before* xterm can see the events.  In the **`translations`** resource, that is this line:

```
      Shift  Insert:insert-selection(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
```

The **`SELECT`** keyword in this resource is interpreted by xterm to be either PRIMARY or CLIPBOARD, depending on the `selectToClipboard` resource (or the *Select to Clipboard* menu entry).  By the way, CLIPBOARD is not the secondary selection.  See [2.6.1.2. The SECONDARY Selection](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6.1.2) in the ICCM for a description of the secondary selection.

You can enable the [`selectToClipboard`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:selectToClipboard) resource by adding this to your `$HOME/.Xdefaults` file (or other resource file, even using `xrdb`):

```
xterm*selectToClipboard: true
```

You can also add translations using `control` and `shift` modifiers (in either order), and the `insert` key.  Adapting my answer in the other question:

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
                 Shift <Key>Insert:    insert-selection(SELECT) \n\
                 Ctrl <Key>Insert:     copy-selection(SELECT) \n\
                 Ctrl Shift <Key>V:    insert-selection(SELECT) \n\
                 Ctrl Shift <Key>C:    copy-selection(SELECT)
```

The translations parser in X Toolkit recognizes a variety of spellings for the keywords.  Thus `Key` is the same as `KeyPress` and `KeyDown`.  But `Ctrl` is the only way it knows for the <kbd>control</kbd> key.

While you *could* add <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, this is generally not recommended because those control keys are useful (by default) in your terminal:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Further reading:

- [Why can't I select/paste to/from other programs?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_select_clipboard) (xterm FAQ)
- [Chapter 10. Translation Management](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXt/intrinsics.html#Translation_Management) (X Toolkit Intrinsics - C Language Interface)
- [Appendix B. Translation Table Syntax](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXt/intrinsics.html#Translation_Table_Syntax) (X Toolkit Intrinsics - C Language Interface)